# Creating and validating a reference number

Tags: java, netbeans-8

So basically, I need to get the user to enter a reference number; it cannot be automatically generated.

It needs to be 2 Numbers, a Letter and a Number again.

Here's my code, but I cannot for the life me get it working, I had it working via a way that automatically generates a reference number, but now we need to change it so it gets the user to manually generate one and I'm just sat staring at NetBeans like "Oh errmmmm..."

```
 static String getReferenceNumber() { 
   Scanner refScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String referNumber = null;
    System.out.println("Please enter a Reference Number");
    System.out.println("It must be 2 Letters and 3 Numbers and a Number"); 
    String input = refScanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();  
    while (!Policy.refCheck(input)) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a Reference Number");
        System.out.println("It must be 2 Letters and 3 Numbers a Nuber");




    if (input.length() !=5) {
        referNumber = false;
    } else if ((!Character.isLetter(input.charAt(0)))
            ||!Character.isLetter(input.charAt(1))
            ||!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(2))
            ||!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(3))
            ||!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(4))){

    referNumber = false;
}


    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(referNumber); 
    return referNumber;
}
```

Comment: When you say "numbers", do you mean "digits"? `0`, `1`, ... `9` are digits. `1`, `42`, `365` are numbers. *Numbers* consists of one or more *digits*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign the actual input to the referNumber, instead you just assign Booleans?

Therefore at the end you are returning a Boolean or null when the return value needs to be a string.

```
static String getReferenceNumber() { 
    Scanner refScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String referNumber = "";
    boolean test = false;  
    while (!test) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a Reference Number");
        System.out.println("It must be 2 Letters and 3 Numbers:");

        String input = refScanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        if (input.length() !=5) {
            test = false;
            System.out.println("Invalid reference");
        } else if ((!Character.isLetter(input.charAt(0)))
            ||!Character.isLetter(input.charAt(1))
            ||!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(2))
            ||!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(3))
            ||!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(4))){

           test = false;
           System.out.println("Invalid reference");
        } else {
            referNumber = input;
            test = true;
        } 
    }
    System.out.println(referNumber);
    return referNumber;
}
```

I have changed the condition for the while loop and altered your if statements. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, how would I go about correcting this? I'm kinda useless this early after finishing work at half 3 this morning ha!

Comment: @Jamie you will have to actually assign input to referNumber. Then if the reference is not in the correct format, assign "false" to the reference number, otherwise return referNumber.

Comment: @Jamie I also think there is a problem with your while loop. I

Comment: @Jamie give me about half an hour until I am on a computer and I will post a coded solution.

Comment: @Jamie The code has been corrected. Please mark it as answered if this is what you need, if not let me know what needs changing :)